# select by option always return same value - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've the below html.

```
<table border="1" id="myTable">
<tr>
<th><b>CheckList</b></th>
<th><b>Health</b></th>
<th><b>Comments</b></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="checklist">TPS on Desktop</td>
<td class="tdcolor">
   <select id="health">
      <option value=0>Select</option>
      <option value="1">Green</option>
      <option value="2">Amber</option>
      <option value="3">Red</option>
   </select>  
</td>
<td><textarea id="comments" type="text" name='Comments'></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="checklist">TPS on Mobile</td>
<td class="tdcolor">
   <select id="health">
     <option value=0>Select</option>
     <option value="1">Green</option>
     <option value="2">Amber</option>
     <option value="3">Red</option>
   </select>  
</td>
<td><textarea id="comments" type="text" name='Comments'></textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<center><input id="saveButton" type="submit" value="Save & Continue"></center>
```

Have written below jquery to extract data in my td cells.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#saveButton').click(function() {
     $('#myTable tr:not(:first-child)').each(function(){
       var checklistText =$(this).find('#checklist').text();
       var commentsText = $(this).find('#comments').val();
       var selectedText ;
        $('select').each(function() {
          selectedText = $('#health option:selected').text();
        });
        alert(checklistText+' : '+selectedText);
     });
    });
});
```

If I select `Green` in first row and select `Amber` in second row, I expect output to be `TPS on Desktop : Green` and `TPS on Mobile : Amber`.

But, the output is always `TPS on Desktop : Green` and `TPS on Mobile : Green`. The second select value is never picked up but the first value of td is picked up.

Any help would be of great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's because you used same id in each one. same id's for different html element are not correct when dealing with jquery

Comment: hmm., I've not faced this situation before. Could you please pass some hints how I can fix this? Thanks

Comment: Use class instead of id

Comment: @harshavmb  added that in my solution

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `id` to `class` and then a bit change in jquery code and it will work.

Example:-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#saveButton').click(function() {
     $('#myTable tr:not(:first-child)').each(function(){
       var checklistText =$(this).find('#checklist').text();
       var commentsText = $(this).find('#comments').val();
       //check code change here
       var selectedText = $(this).find('.health option:selected').text();
        alert(checklistText+' : '+selectedText);
     });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="myTable">
<tr>
<th><b>CheckList</b></th>
<th><b>Health</b></th>
<th><b>Comments</b></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="checklist">TPS on Desktop</td>
<td class="tdcolor">
   <select class="health"><!-- convert id to class-->
  <option value=0>Select</option>
  <option value="1">Green</option>
  <option value="2">Amber</option>
  <option value="3">Red</option>
   </select>  
</td>
<td><textarea id="comments" type="text" name='Comments'></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="checklist">TPS on Mobile</td>
<td class="tdcolor">
   <select class="health"><!-- convert id to class-->
  <option value=0>Select</option>
  <option value="1">Green</option>
  <option value="2">Amber</option>
  <option value="3">Red</option>
   </select>  
</td>
<td><textarea id="comments" type="text" name='Comments'></textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<center><input id="saveButton" type="submit" value="Save & Continue"></center>
```

***Note:-***

***The snippet:-*** `$('select').each(function() {selectedText = $('#health option:selected').text();});` actually not needed because you are applying `each()` on `<tr>` already.

Comment: harshavmb  glad to help you friend.

Answer (score 2):

You have named both td `checklist`. An id should be unique. You should use class instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#saveButton').click(function() {
     $('#myTable tr:not(:first-child)').each(function(){
       var checklistText =$(this).find('.checklist').text();
       var commentsText = $(this).find('#comments').val();
       var selectedText ;
       selectedText = $(this).find('.health option:selected').text();
       alert(checklistText+' : '+selectedText);
     });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="myTable">
<tr>
<th><b>CheckList</b></th>
<th><b>Health</b></th>
<th><b>Comments</b></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="checklist1" class="checklist">TPS on Desktop</td>
<td class="tdcolor">
   <select id="health1" class="health">
             <option value=0>Select</option>
             <option value="1">Green</option>
             <option value="2">Amber</option>
             <option value="3">Red</option>
   </select>  
</td>
<td><textarea id="comments" type="text" name='Comments'></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="checklist2" class="checklist">TPS on Mobile</td>
<td class="tdcolor">
   <select id="health2" class="health">
             <option value=0>Select</option>
             <option value="1">Green</option>
             <option value="2">Amber</option>
             <option value="3">Red</option>
   </select>  
</td>
<td><textarea id="comments" type="text" name='Comments'></textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<center><input id="saveButton" type="submit" value="Save & Continue"></center>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote. In fact I upvoted.. Not sure who did it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

```
$('select').each(function() {
    selectedText = $('#health option:selected').text();
});
```

here you are looping with every select element but always getting the value of `$('#health')` select. Change it to:

```
$('select').each(function() {
    selectedText = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
});
```

and try again.

Answer (score 1):

you colud use like this .you are using same `id` .`id` is on unique, so only it returning first selected value not take with second  one.so use with `$(this)` .it will validate each `row` inside the `select`

```
$(this).find('select').each(function() {
        selectedText = $(this).children('option:selected').text();
      });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#saveButton').click(function() {
    $('#myTable tr:not(:first-child)').each(function() {
      var checklistText = $(this).find('#checklist').text();
      var commentsText = $(this).find('#comments').val();
      var selectedText;
      $(this).find('select').each(function() {
        selectedText = $(this).children('option:selected').text();
      });
      alert(checklistText + ' : ' + selectedText);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th><b>CheckList</b></th>
    <th><b>Health</b></th>
    <th><b>Comments</b></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="checklist">TPS on Desktop</td>
    <td class="tdcolor">
      <select id="health">
             <option value=0>Select</option>
             <option value="1">Green</option>
             <option value="2">Amber</option>
             <option value="3">Red</option>
   </select>
    </td>
    <td><textarea id="comments" type="text" name='Comments'></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="checklist">TPS on Mobile</td>
    <td class="tdcolor">
      <select id="health">
             <option value=0>Select</option>
             <option value="1">Green</option>
             <option value="2">Amber</option>
             <option value="3">Red</option>
   </select>
    </td>
    <td><textarea id="comments" type="text" name='Comments'></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<center><input id="saveButton" type="submit" value="Save & Continue"></center>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is very simple one. Whatever value you will select in second dropdown, script will alert value of 1st dropdown and the reason behind this is same "id=health". Everytime script is executed it will get the element from the top and it will use that element which is found in first. So use unique id for both the dropdown.

*"Using $() with an id selector as its argument will return a jQuery object containing a collection of either zero or one DOM element.
Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM. This behavior should not be relied on, however; a document with more than one element using the same ID is invalid."*

Answer (score 0):

My JS fiddle went useless.. The actual issue is you using same elt ID repeatedly

https://jsfiddle.net/jinspeter/3qokLuff/

```
    <table border="1" id="myTable">
<tr>
<th><b>CheckList</b></th>
<th><b>Health</b></th>
<th><b>Comments</b></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="checklist">TPS on Desktop</td>
<td class="tdcolor">
   <select class="health">
             <option value=0>Select</option>
             <option value="1">Green</option>
             <option value="2">Amber</option>
             <option value="3">Red</option>
   </select>  
</td>
<td><textarea class="comments" type="text" name='Comments'></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="checklist">TPS on Mobile</td>
<td class="tdcolor">
   <select class="health">
             <option value=0>Select</option>
             <option value="1">Green</option>
             <option value="2">Amber</option>
             <option value="3">Red</option>
   </select>  
</td>
<td><textarea class="comments" type="text" name='Comments'></textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<center><input id="saveButton" type="submit" value="Save & Continue"></center>

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#saveButton').click(function() {
     $('#myTable tr:not(:first-child)').each(function(){
       var checklistText =$(this).find('.checklist').text();
       var commentsText = $(this).find('.comments').val();
       var selectedText = $(this).find('select.health option:selected').text();

        alert(checklistText+' : '+selectedText);
     });
    });
});
```